# javascript not resetting what is in the textbox when the button is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am new with this thing! I want the value of the textbox field to not be deleted even if the form is submitted

Here is my html page

```
     <form action="" method="post">
     <label>Firstname: </label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
     <label>Lastname: </label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
     <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
     </form>
```

This is just a little sample

I want that if he already inputted a firstname and not inputted lastname, the inputted firstname will stay, while there will be an error in the lastname, how will I do that? because if I have a big form, specially a registration form, when i press the button and the client will got it wrong all what is inside the textbox will reset, instead of just remaining the correct things, it is not a very user-friendly thing right? thanks for helping me!

Comment: Do you post data to the same page and want to validate data in server side? or client side? in Client Side the data wont disappear before submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload=function(){
a=function(b){
return document.getElementById(b);
};

var elems=[
//add all element ids here:
a("fname"),a("lastname")
];


elems.forEach(function(elem){
//restore
elem.value=localStorage.getItem(elem.id);

//add EventListener
elem.onchange=function(){
localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);
}
});
};
```

This stores the value to the localStorage when it is changed and writes it back into the field when the page is reloaded